# How to install phemex api

Tags: python, api

Can somebody tell me how to isntall phemex api in python.
I tried:
`pip install phemex`
But there is only the error:
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement phemex (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for phemex`

How to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: This error means that there isn't a library named "phemex" on PyPI. I don't know how to help you with that.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/phemex/ doesn't exist. The search finds nothing too: https://pypi.org/search/?q=phemex

Comment: Yes, but how can I install it on a other way?

Answer (score 1):

I found the repo. The library isn't uploaded on PyPI. However, you can still install it through Github with the following command:

```py
pip install git+https://github.com/phemex/phemex-python-api
```

Comment: If I try this, I get this error ´ERROR: git+https://github.com/phemex/phemex-python-api does not appear to be a Python project: neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.´

Comment: Hmph, you might need to install it from the source and locate it in python's `site-packages path.

Comment: How to install from source? Do I have to download the github files and put it into my site-package folder?

Comment: I guess so, put the inner folder named `phemex` from it to your `site-packages` folder

Comment: Ok, the command import phemex does work now. But if I try "from phemex import Client" that does not work. There is an Import ERror "ImportError: cannot import name 'Client'"

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to install the lib, just copy the code into your project and append the path to sys.path, for example

```
<your project root>
 -| lib/phemex/
 -| src/yourcode.py
```

in yourcode.py, simply add below in order to use the api

```
import os 
import sys

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(dir_path + "../lib")

from phemex.client import Client
from phemex.exceptions import PhemexAPIException
```